# Tomcat Jenkins Git error of repo

Tags: git, tomcat, jenkins

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command:  ls-remote -h https://github.com/amit-walia/my-own-test.git HEAD
```

[image]

[image]

Please help as i am not able to search the exact solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't available, but I assume this message is on the screen where you are setting up your job. You probably don't have git in the path for the user who is running Jenkins. Even if you add git as a tool, Jenkins still needs to know where to find git to do the initial connection validation when you setup the job. Ignore this error and see if the job actually runs. If it is actually configured right, and you are using a git tool, then it will likely run fine. It is just that initial validate that fails.

Comment: i am not able to build the repo in jenkins. Build coming failed. in my previous it was normally successful.

Comment: I think you are still missing git. Create a simple freestyle job without a git checkout and just run a shell script with "git --version". I suspect it won't be able to find git.